# Which browsers should my website work perfectly on

Tags: testing, browser

I want to learn the best and most effective way to test my website in different browsers, and therefore if the website does not render to my satisfaction I would like to be aware of how to improve the website and how far can the improvements go: for example, if something does not work in IE, I would like to be able to take a judgement of whether this "something" can be improved or whether that is just the price IE users have to pay.

1) which browsers should I test my website on

2) which browsers should I have installed (in windows)?

3) is there any "must know" website which explains the way the above browsers work (or would I get enough information through searching on google)

Thanks for you help

Comment: I would try answering 3) experimentally.  Plug what you want to know into google and see if you get enough information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple answer of your question is available on this link:

**http://www.w3schools.com/browsers/browsers_stats.asp**

Above link will show you clear statistics of browsers.

Moreover is that that

1) which browsers should I test my website on
Ans: it depends upon your audience and you should at least test on top browsers i.e. IE 8, FireFox and Chrome

2) which browsers should I have installed (in windows)?

Answer: All possible.
3) is there any "must know" website which explains the way the above browsers work (or would I get enough information through searching on google)

Answer: w3c will surely help you in this regard.

Regards
husnain

Answer (score 1):

Consider [Selenium HQ](http://seleniumhq.org/). It's an automated testing tool that let's you script tests using Firefox, Chrome, and IE.

Answer (score 0):

This link will be very helpfull:

http://www.freakzion.com/index.php/The-Blog-May-2013/browser-compatibility.html

Basically should be these ones:

- Firefox 6
- Chrome 22
- Explorer 8
- Safari 5
- Opera 11